# SVG (?) causing white space

Tags: html, css, svg, background, whitespace

First of all, I am using SVG's, and that's already kind of difficult as it is, I could not get the background image to work at all, neither through CSS or the `img src` tag.

One known hack with SVG's is the `padding-bottom hack` but im not familiar with them enough. This has been the only way SVG's has seem to work, by copying the shape, on Adobe Illustrator, then `CTRL + V` on Visual Studio Code. How can I get rid of all that extra space below?

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="svg-wrap">
        <svg class="svg-item" width="auto" height="100">
            <rect x="20" width="20" height="400" fill="white" />
            <rect x="60" width="20" height="400" fill="white" />
            <rect x="100" width="20" height="400" fill="white" />
        </svg>
    </div>
        <ul class="nav-items">
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This block of code contains the navbar part and also the three rectangles near the left corner

```
    <div class="svg-wrap">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="100 0 600 1200">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
            </style>
            <path class="st0" d="M0,1c118.8,0,118.8,20,237.6,20C356.4,21,356.4,1,475.2,1C594,1,594,21,712.8,21C831.6,21,831.6,1,950.4,1
                        s118.8,20,237.6,20"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

This next batch is the wavy path below the navbar

```
    <svg class="left-svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="99.7px" height="792.7px"
    viewBox="10 12 99.7 792.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 99.7 792.7;">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="0.4" x2="0.4" y2="99.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="99.4" x2="0.4" y2="198.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="198.4" x2="0.4" y2="297.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="297.4" x2="0.4" y2="396.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="396.4" x2="0.4" y2="495.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="495.4" x2="0.4" y2="594.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="594.4" x2="0.4" y2="693.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="99.4" y1="693.4" x2="0.4" y2="792.4"/>
</svg>
```

This is the left side of the page

```
<svg class="right-svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="99.7px" height="792.7px"
viewBox="12 12 99.7 792.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 99.7 792.7;">
    <style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="0.4" x2="99.4" y2="99.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="99.4" x2="99.4" y2="198.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="198.4" x2="99.4" y2="297.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="297.4" x2="99.4" y2="396.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="396.4" x2="99.4" y2="495.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="495.4" x2="99.4" y2="594.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="594.4" x2="99.4" y2="693.4"/>
    <line class="st0" x1="0.4" y1="693.4" x2="99.4" y2="792.4"/>
</svg>
```

And lastly the above code is the right side of the page.

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    height: 80px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2;
}

.svg-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.svg-item {
    padding: 16px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}

.left-svg {
    position: relative;
    top: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.right-svg {
    position: relative;
    top: 45px;
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}
```

I really wish there would be a cleaner/shorter way to show you guys my code, but some of the SVG code is around other HTML content, thus making it very long and tedious. Also I know that by pasting the CSS just make things worse!! Hope im not breaking any spamming rule, this is what i considered what should be of interest, I have included a little [video](https://streamable.com/m5vp0) so you can see how and where the extra space is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="100 0 600 1200">
```

Your viewbox is having 600 width and 1200 height.
So try to specify a lesser width and height for it and check

Comment: yep! totally right. i forgot i made it like that, such newb he-he!! thanks!

Comment: If its working then please mark the question as closed

Comment: i guess "accepting" your answer closes it? :o not sure but i just did accepted it.